# Run browser JS in Node.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, cross-platform

I wrote some basic javascript code in AngularJs. I want to be able to run this code in Node.js but keep the possibility to run it in the browser depending the situation.

I know that it is possible do run Node.js code in the browser by using browserify or lobrow but I did not find a solution to run browser code in Node.js

Thanks in advance for your answers

Daniel

Answer (score 1):

First a warning. NO DOM manipulation in your module since node has no DOM. Also if you need to `require` anything in your module you really should be looking at Browserify et al.

Your module would look like this

```
(function(){
    var sayHello = function(name) {
       return "Hello " + name;
    };

    // here's the interesting part
    if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports) {  // we're in NodeJS
        module.exports = sayHello;
    } else {                                                // we're in a browser
        window.sayHello = sayHello;
    }

})();
```

In node

```
var sayHello = require('./myModule');
console.log(sayHello("Node"));        // => "Hello Node"
```

and in your browser

```
<script src="myModule.js"></script>
<script>
  console.log(sayHello("Browser"));   // => "Hello Browser"
</script>
```